# using barcodescanner phonegap-.plugin ANDROID

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Ok here is the deal I did everything on [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner) I also add the code to the manifest taking care is inside the  and add the permisions also edit the xml file located at my res folder... then create a `com/phonegap/plugins/barcodescanner` and add the BArcodeScanner.java file to it. Them inport to my html `<script src="barcodescanner.js"> </script>` that is located on the same directory as the html...

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Validacion de usuarios</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/decoracion.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="inicio">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Autenticacion de Usuario</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   

            <input type="button" onclick="scanCode();" value="SCAN">
    </div>

</div>




<script>
function scanCode() {
alert("ENTRA");
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                  "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                  "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                  "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                }
    );};
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem comes when I press the button I know that it enters the function but it doesn't open the camara or anything just stay there. Is that suppost to happend? anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I was really dumb and didn't import the barcodescanner.js to the html file